# Better way to let user attach and open files

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

I need to add a feature to my winforms app to let the user attach and open files. Right now, I have a datagridview with a column named File Name. The user must put the full file path into that column, then it opens up the file on click. The sub I have to handle this runs on content click and is as follows:

```
try
    process.start(files.currentcell.value)
catch
    msgbox("file not found")
end try
```

Are there any other ways I could set this up? I dont like how they have to copy the entire file path into the cell, but the files are all of different types and in various different folders on the computer. any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `OpenFileDialog`it is easy to use look it up on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here is how to use it:

```
 openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() 'Open the dialog
 Dim path As String = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString() 'get the selected path
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: nice, c# syntex of vb.net question :)

Comment: @AliAshraf I still figured it out haha